# How to fix this in XSLT 3.0? (<xsl:merge>)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I wish to explain <xsl:merge>.

This used to work years ago, but not anymore:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="3.0" 
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
      xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
   <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:merge bind-group="g" bind-key="k">
       <xsl:merge-source for-each="(1,100)" select="(.*5,.*3,.*1,.*7,.*9)">
          <xsl:merge-key select="."/>
       </xsl:merge-source>
       <xsl:merge-source select="(4,10,2,8,6)">
          <xsl:merge-key select=". * 10" order="descending"/>
       </xsl:merge-source>
       <xsl:merge-source select="(5)">
          <xsl:merge-key select=". * 10"/>
       </xsl:merge-source>
       <xsl:merge-action>
         <xsl:value-of select="$g"/>
         <xsl:text>&#32;</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="$k"/>
         <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
       </xsl:merge-action>
     </xsl:merge>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

How can I create a demo that best explains XSLT merging for my readers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec since 2017 is online at https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#merge-instruction so perhaps start there, I am not sure where your syntax comes from, whether that is from an older working draft or from some other implementation.

The closest I could come up with is e.g.

```
   <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
     <xsl:merge>
       <xsl:merge-source for-each-item="(1,100)" select="(.*5,.*3,.*1,.*7,.*9)" sort-before-merge="yes">
          <xsl:merge-key select="."/>
       </xsl:merge-source>
       <xsl:merge-source select="(4,10,2,8,6)" sort-before-merge="yes">
          <xsl:merge-key select=". * 10"/>
       </xsl:merge-source>
       <xsl:merge-source select="(5)">
          <xsl:merge-key select=". * 10"/>
       </xsl:merge-source>
       <xsl:merge-action>
         <xsl:value-of select="current-merge-group()"/>
         <xsl:text>&#32;</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="current-merge-key()"/>
         <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
       </xsl:merge-action>
     </xsl:merge>
   </xsl:template>
```

Works [online with SaxonJS](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Atransform%20version%3D%223.0%22%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Afn%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amerge%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amerge-source%20for-each-item%3D%22%281%2C100%29%22%20select%3D%22%28.*5%2C.*3%2C.*1%2C.*7%2C.*9%29%22%20sort-before-merge%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amerge-key%20select%3D%22.%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Amerge-source%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amerge-source%20select%3D%22%284%2C10%2C2%2C8%2C6%29%22%20sort-before-merge%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amerge-key%20select%3D%22.%20*%2010%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Amerge-source%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amerge-source%20select%3D%22%285%29%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amerge-key%20select%3D%22.%20*%2010%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Amerge-source%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amerge-action%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22current-merge-group%28%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atext%3E%26%2332%3B%3C%2Fxsl%3Atext%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22current-merge-key%28%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atext%3E%26%2310%3B%3C%2Fxsl%3Atext%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Amerge-action%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Amerge%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Atransform%3E&input=&input-type=None).